# Getting this error while working with django : FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I have created a BaseUser model to create users and i have also created a Profile for every single user when new user gets created.

But when i try to update the information's or try to delete the specific user from the admin panel i get this error :-

```
[12/Jan/2024 15:05:29] "GET /admin/accounts/baseuser/16/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17895
[12/Jan/2024 15:05:30] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 347
Not Found: /favicon.ico
Internal Server Error: /admin/accounts/baseuser/16/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 313, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1889, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1747, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 263, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 337, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 313, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/mohit/okk/django_pinterest/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 313, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[12/Jan/2024 15:05:32] "POST /admin/accounts/baseuser/16/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 129157
```

this is how i created my models :-

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager,AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin

from .manager import MyUserManager
# Create your models here.

class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="email address",
        max_length=255,
        
    )
    joined_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)    

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
    



class Profile(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(default='profiles/default.png', upload_to='profiles')
    about = models.TextField()
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pronouns = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

and this is my signals.py :-

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import BaseUser,Profile



@receiver(post_save,sender=BaseUser)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save,sender = BaseUser)
def save_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Please help me if you could.. i have been stuck from tomorrow.

Comment: Did you make sure to migrate before trying to execute operations? Also, could you share the code for `MyUserManager`?